# Just receive half data from server (ESP8266 ESP-01 module + UNO)

Tags: http, arduino, wifi

My php file on server. Just simpe php program. It will send back respond to my ESP8266 :

```
<?php
       ECHO $_GET['subject'];
       ECHO "SELAMAT DATANG";
?>
```

My sketch in arduino uno. Just in loop() :

```
void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 
 data="subject=anis";
 String requestGet="GET /index.php HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: nyalalampu.atwebpages.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Length: "+String(data.length())+"\r\n\r\n"+data;
 
 anis.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"nyalalampu.atwebpages.com\",80\r\n");
 delay(2000);
 while(anis.available()>0)
 {
   char c=anis.read();
 }

 anis.println("AT+CIPSEND="+String(requestGet.length()+2)+"\r\n");
 delay(2000);
 while(anis.available()>0)
 {
   char c=anis.read();
 }

 anis.println(requestGet);
 delay(1);
 while(anis.available()>0)
 {
   String a=anis.readString();
   Serial.println(a);
 }

 anis.println("AT+CIPCLOSE\r\n");
 delay(1000);
 while(anis.available()>0)
 {
   char c=anis.read();
 }
}
```

Data i receive from server :

```
+IPD,165:HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2020 22:46:16 GMT

Serve hes-/e

T
```

It looks like i just receive half data from server and other lost. Can someone show me somelight or tell me what's wrong with my sketch? TQ

Comment: Change `delay(1);` to longer value, 165 bytes of data take longer to come in.

Comment: serial is slow so there are gaps between received characters so available() sometimes returns 0

Comment: @Juraj Tq sir...did you have any tutorial that i can solve my problem?

Comment: I use readBytesUntil.https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readbytesuntil/

Comment: @Juraj Alhamdulillah...tq sir...it's working for me...